# Failed to add a custom field in settings

Tags: error-message, globals, custom-field

I'm trying to add a global set, with a Matrix and two required fields for a product. This always works.

Now that I am in version 2.6.2791 it fails to add the fields with error:

`Warning</b>
: Declaration of Craft\UserSessionService::login($username, $password, $rememberMe = false) should be compatible with CWebUser::login($identity, $duration = 0) in
<b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft-app/2.6.2791/services/UserSessionService.php</b>
on line
<b>17</b>
<br>
<br>
<b>Warning</b>
: Declaration of Craft\UserSessionService::afterLogin() should be compatible with CWebUser::afterLogin($fromCookie) in
<b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft-app/2.6.2791/services/UserSessionService.php</b>
on line
<b>17</b>
<br>
<br>
<b>Warning</b>
: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft-app/2.6.2791/services/UserSessionService.php:17) in
<b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft-app/2.6.2791/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php</b>
on line
<b>1519</b>
<br>
<br>
<b>Warning</b>
: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft-app/2.6.2791/services/UserSessionService.php:17) in
<b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft-app/2.6.2791/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php</b>
on line
<b>1507</b>`

The CSRF token could not be validated.

Any ideas or fixes would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error message because your PHP environment is displaying [PHP Strict mode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) error messages.

By default, Craft will explicitly disable those if [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) is enabled (`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);`) and disable all messages if devMode is disabled (`error_reporting(0);`).

So my guess is you've either got a plugin that's messing with error_reporting and re-enabling strict messages or you've doing it from your public `index.php` or `craft/config` files.

Note that in the upcoming Craft 3, we've made it so that you can run Craft with PHP strict error messaging enabled.